# How to fixed "cordova platform add android" error in ionic

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to add an Android platform for my ionic 2 projects using "ionic cordova platform add android". But it gives "[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova." Any solution?

Comment: Provide full error logs of your console that appears while adding a new android platform.

Comment: What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: try and run with a debug flag

Comment: can you explain with more details?? how to run with debug flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to reinstalling cordova.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

I hope this help